# Drawing sine waves effeciently in android

Tags: java, android, waveform, sine-wave

I am making an app where I need to draw a sine wave between two given points. I have Google'd, and Google'd, and I haven't found anything that I have found suitable.

Is there an efficient way in android to use some pre defined points to draw a smooth wave like form?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking here.  There are at least three ways to interpret what you just said.  Do you:  1.  Want the equation for a parametric curve passing through 2 points which has sinusoidal oscillations?  2. Want to interpolate a triangle wave with a sine wave?  3.  Just want to know how to quickly plot a sine wave?

Comment: looking for the interpolation if you know. the wavelength is the same for the whole wave, but the amplitude is random for each point

Comment: that doesn't make much sense.  What you are asking for is not a sine wave then, but is in fact something else.  If you can vary the amplitude freely, you can make any function you want.

Comment: Bit late but look at my similar problem and how I solved it http://stackoverflow.com/a/19520120/1112882

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [android.graphics.Path](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html) class to construct a set of quadratic or cubic  [Bézier spline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_spline) curves between your set of control points.

Comment: any chance you have an example of this?

Comment: @DingleNutZ were you able to create sine wave ?