# Fill Sine Graph Android

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have this code:

```
public class TestView extends View {

private Path mPath;
private Paint mPaint = new Paint();

public TestView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public TestView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public TestView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    mPath = new Path();
    mPath.moveTo(0, 0);
    mPath.quadTo(50, -50, 100, 0);
    mPath.quadTo(150, 50, 200, 0);
    mPath.quadTo(250, -50, 300, 0);
    mPath.quadTo(350, 50, 400, 0);
    mPath.quadTo(450, -50, 500, 0);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(0, getMeasuredHeight() / 2F);
    // just making sure to clip starting and ending curve
    canvas.clipRect(50, -100, 450, 100, Region.Op.INTERSECT);
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    canvas.restore();
}
}
```

That produces this:

[image]

But I want this (pardon my Paint skills):

[image]

Any help on filling area under this sine curve will be appreciated.

Comment: what is Region post its import line or implementation, from this line canvas.clipRect(50, -100, 450, 100, Region.Op.INTERSECT);

Comment: @Warlock its `import android.graphics.Region;`;

Comment: @Warlock the problem is solved I just needed to play with `quadTo()` values a bit. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change your values to

```
mPath.moveTo(0,100);
mPath.quadTo(50, -50, 100, 0);
mPath.quadTo(150, 50, 200, 0);
mPath.quadTo(250, -50, 300, 0);
mPath.quadTo(350, 50, 400, 0);
mPath.quadTo(450, -50, 500, 100);
```

Comment: Bit late :) ? I have solved it with similar approach.Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Never mind, this produced what I wanted:

```
    mPath = new Path();
    mPath.moveTo(0, 0);
    mPath.quadTo(50, -100, 100, -50);
    mPath.quadTo(150, -0, 200, -50);
    mPath.quadTo(250, -100, 300, -50);
    mPath.quadTo(350, -0, 400, -50);
    mPath.quadTo(450, -100, 500, -0);
    mPath.close();
```

[image]

Comment: still you dont need to change too much values in my solution :) just the y of start point and end point

Comment: What should be parameter if want to set this as Background in Half of screen.(bottom to half of screen)