# How to create custom shape in Android

Tags: android

In my application I want use **WaterWave** effect on custom shape such as below. 
[image]

I want to change this WaterWave position with percent, for example this percent is 0 to 100. 
When percent is 0 show empty, percent is 100 fill this shape, percent is 50 fill half shape and more ... 
I search many time in google but just find library for **circle** or **heart** shape! 
I can't find any shape such as above shape!

How can I create shape with **WaterWave** such as above image? 
Please help me   Please help me

Comment: https://github.com/race604/WaveLoading try this with using drawable image

Comment: @SandeshKhutalSaheb I try it but in android 30 and above not working :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a custom View and override the `onDraw()` method to calculate the percentage, then draw a mask on top of that to give the droplet effect. The shape of the wave looks like the **sin** function, so you should play around with that, so the view percentage is dynamic. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks my friend, but I don't know how can I create custom shape for this! can you help me and send to me code? please

Comment: Here, this one might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19519856/fill-sine-graph-android