# How to Draw the Audio waves?

Tags: android, audio, wave

I want to Draw the audio waves only. I am also see the RingDroid open Source code But it's so complicated. 
I am only generate the waves like tha

[Sound Waves Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6vi0.png)

Comment: Have you tried anything ? You may try this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6501741/5505915)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drawing sine waves effeciently in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501183/drawing-sine-waves-effeciently-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

take a .wav file and follow this project

https://github.com/newventuresoftware/WaveformControl

Answer (score 1):

Try [This](https://github.com/Semantive/waveform-android) it may be help to you.