# How to make a waves in the layout

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-xml

I am trying to make a view like [this](http://www.materialup.com/posts/profile-views-exploration). I know how to make it curve, circle etc like divider. But how I can make the same type of waves .I am able to make something  [like this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ThirdState.SineLine&hl=en)? But I want to use in as a view.

Comment: refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/6501741/4321808

Comment: I tried that but I don't find any example

Comment: And one more point I want to display it as sine wave lines not like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19519856/fill-sine-graph-android/19520120#19520120

Comment: i think you need to combine a few frequencies to obtain those waves, do you still need it?

Comment: I am getting the able to get the trigonometric waves but how to get this ??@lelloman

Answer (score 0):

checkout this [gist](https://gist.github.com/raviteja83/6d907d200179783c9718553faa759aea).it is a sample of basic sine wave but you can make changes as you need.

Comment: add the view in your xml.The only problem is it is static not dynamic.

Comment: i know that but how i can call the SineView class in java??

Comment: SineView sineview = new SineView(context); you can use any of the constructors if you want to programatically call it.